# Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme le agradecería mucho. Estoy realizando un proyecto que incluye la implementación de un CRUD(Crear, leer, actualizar y borrar) registros de una base de datos de Access conectada con C#

Resulta que cuando ejecuto el programa, ingresa al formulario donde está esta parte del mismo y me aparece un error "Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException'" y en el detalle me dice que el componente ConnectionString no ha sido inicializado, acá dejo la parte del código en la que me muestra esta excepción.

```
public partial class frmCRUD : Form
{
    private int actual;

    public frmCRUD()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        actual = getFirstId();
        showData();
    }
    private int getFirstId()
    {

        this.oleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
        this.oleDbConnection1.Open(); <---------------------------Acá especificamente muestra el error
        this.oleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Connection = oleDbConnection1;

        OleDbDataReader reader = this.oleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        int cedula = Convert.ToInt16(reader["Cedula"].ToString());

        this.oleDbConnection1.Close();

        return cedula;
    }

    private void showData()
    {
        this.oleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE Cedula =" + actual;
        this.oleDbConnection1.Open();
        this.oleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Connection = oleDbConnection1;

        OleDbDataReader reader = this.oleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            txtCedula.Text = reader["Cedula"].ToString();
            txtNombre.Text = reader["Nombre"].ToString();
            txtDireccion.Text = reader["Direccion"].ToString();
            txtTelefono.Text = reader["Telefono"].ToString();
            txtemail.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();
        }

        this.oleDbConnection1.Close();
    }
```

Por favor, agradecería mucho su ayuda, he intentado varias cosas con soluciones que he encontrado en internet pero desafortunadamente nada ha funcionado.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debes colocar la cadena de conexión para que te funcione. Más o menos debería ser así:

```
public partial class frmCRUD : Form
{
    private int actual;

    public frmCRUD()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        actual = getFirstId();
        showData();
    }
    private int getFirstId()
    {
        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=TU_DIRECTORIO\\ARCHIVO.mdb;Persist Security Info=True");

        this.oleDbConnection1 = connect;

        this.oleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
        this.oleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Connection = oleDbConnection1;

        OleDbDataReader reader = this.oleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        int cedula = Convert.ToInt16(reader["Cedula"].ToString());

        this.oleDbConnection1.Close();

        return cedula;
    }

    private void showData()
    {
        this.oleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE Cedula =" + actual;
        this.oleDbConnection1.Open();
        this.oleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Connection = oleDbConnection1;

        OleDbDataReader reader = this.oleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            txtCedula.Text = reader["Cedula"].ToString();
            txtNombre.Text = reader["Nombre"].ToString();
            txtDireccion.Text = reader["Direccion"].ToString();
            txtTelefono.Text = reader["Telefono"].ToString();
            txtemail.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();
        }

        this.oleDbConnection1.Close();
    }
```

Asumiendo que tu base de datos es Access.

Comment: Muchas gracias Christian, solucionaste gran parte de mi problema.